# crontab -e , then 0 * * * * = every hour... Where is stored

Tags: linux, cron

After sudo crontab -e 
(it wrote "/tmp/crontab.XXXX70pN9h" 1L, 19C            1,1           All

Then I saved the file. And to check..? (how? i don't know)

```
And to check I 
ps -e | grep cron
29818 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

So.. but I decided to check again but

```
sudo cat /etc/cron.hourly
cat: /etc/cron.hourly: Is a directory
xi@localhost ~ $ sudo ls /etc/cron.hourly
```

Nothing! i.e. in directory

As I understand first 0 in the hour-position means every hour?

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for an hour (the most lessest gap in documentation)

Comment: You definitely want to check a question of mine. It has an answer by Stephane Chazelas that explains how you can create an interactive shell that is identical to the environment your cron job will see. If you walk through his little procedure, you get a prompt and you can test your cronjob step by step and see where it fails. unix.stackexchange.com/a/56503/16841 Sure it isn't a 100% match for your question, but it can help you troubleshoot crontab issues.

Answer (score 25):

The fields in cron are:

```
m      h       dom             mon     dow          command
Minute Hour    Day of Month    Month   Day of week  <command>
```

And your `0 * * * * <command>` then translates to "Execute command on every hour, every day, every month, and every weekday, if the minute is 0"

You can list your crontab by using `crontab -l`, as delh already stated.

Take this Link here, there are some [Practical Cron Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
it's like , But visa versa

Comment: What does this have to do with cron?

Answer (score 10):

Your `crontab` and `cron.hourly` are separate entities. Putting something in your `crontab` does not put it in `cron.hourly`, even if it runs every hour. Putting a script in `cron.hourly` is merely *another* way of having it run every hour, that is, your `cron` daemon checks both your `crontab` *and* `cron.hourly`. Having it in both would run it twice.

Comment: Fri Nov  9 15:16:01 EET 2012
xi@localhost ~ $ ls /var/log/cron.log
ls: cannot access /var/log/cron.log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the crontab is installed using:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

Every hour a log message should appear in `/var/log/syslog` that it was executed.

Further reading:

http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial

I tink that the first zero (0) is the minutes. But if you say you want something done when the minutes is 0 it would be performed every hour. As only once an hour the minutes are zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run a cron by the following tutorial

http://answergig.com/48/please-provide-some-linux-cron-job-examples?show=48#q48

```
0 * * * *  /path
```

Comment: Normally we don't really like link-only answers a lot, because links can die over time. Can you reproduce maybe the main steps of the linked page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually looking for user cron files to see when it's changed or something of that nature it can be found at `/var/spool/cron/` but you probably shouldn't manipulate the files manually.

Comment: Not so much _probably shouldn't_ as _should not_. The `cron` daemon won't notice changes if you edit the files directly. Instead, use `crontab -l` to list for the current user, `crontab -e` to edit for the current user, and/or include `-u {user}` as well to access that different user's `crontab`. This is all well defined in the [man page for `crontab`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).

Comment: I believe there are ways to set `cron` to automatically check the files for changes if you _really_ need to update them manually.

Comment: If you need to update them manually then use the `crontab` interface; that's what it's there for. Otherwise you're going to have to stop and restart the `cron` daemon.