# Who can use cron? Who is using cron?

Tags: cron

I want to run cron every minute OR hour xclock.

Comment: "/tmp/crontab.XXXXtxJdHs" 1L, 19C

Comment: crontab -e */1 * * * xclock

Comment: o you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.XXXXtxJdHs

Comment: Wait a minute for my xclock

Comment: crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXsDZzNM":1: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.XXXXsDZzNM

Comment: man vixie-cron
No manual entry for vixie-cron

Comment: xi@localhost ~ $ sudo cat /tmp/crontab.XXXXsDZzNM
*/1 * * * * *  xclock 
xi@localhost ~ $

Comment: no xclock Is there

Comment: gentoo , using vixie-cron

Comment: I find your comments quite confusing, are you narrating your attempts?

Comment: Yes, is it wrong?

Comment: It helps considerably if you have a specific question in mind and you've already put some effort into solving it. You asked three cron-related questions right in a row, as if you're posting every time you run into a problem. Try to get things set up, and then if you have a specific issue and you can't find anything in the documentation, ask one specific question about it

Answer (score 2):

Delh's answer is partly wrong: */1 * * * * won't run a command hourly.

`*/1 * * * *  YourCommandHere` would run the command every minute.

To start a job every hour:

`0 * * * *  YourCommandHere` on Minute "0"

`15 * * * *  YourCommandHere` on Minute 15, just as an example

`*/2 * * * *  YourCommandHere` Runs the command every two minutes

`0 */3 * * *  YourCommandHere` Runs the command every 3 Hours, when the Minute is 0

And to add to that: his questions seems like it could be merged up with [crontab -e , then 0 * * * * = every hour... Where is stored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55287/crontab-e-then-0-every-hour-then-xclock)

Comment: My fault, edited my answer. Guess I shouldn't be posting in a sleep deprived state! +1

Comment: Hehe, i know that state very well... :)

Answer (score 1):

To add or remove a cronjob use the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

if this comes up with your least favourite editor (nano for me) you can use something like this to change that:

```
export EDITOR=vim|vi|nano|ed
```

Each line represents a scheduled job, unless it is commented with a `#`.

The six fields have the following values:

m h dom mon dow command

To define the time you can provide concrete values for minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon), and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').

To execute a command every minute add a command like this:

```
/1 * * * * YourCommandHere
```

To execute a command every two minutes it would look like this:

```
/2 * * * * YourCommandHere
```

To run a job every hour:

```
0 * * * *  YourCommandHere
```

To run a job at 5 a.m every week with:

```
0 5 * * 1  YourCommandHere
```

To see what jobs are scheduled for your account use the command:

```
crontab -l
```

A log entry should appear in `/var/log/syslog` when a job is run.

Comment: Your “every hour” code misses a space.

Comment: from `man 5 crontab`:  `if  you  want  to  say 'every two hours', just use */2'`.

Comment: Ok, then your “every hour” code misses an asterisk.

Comment: I tested it and you are so right! Thanks. The `*/n` thing is always a bit confusing as to count it as one or two positions.

Comment: @delh - The slash syntax is not portable to many Unixes.

Comment: @JodieC It's not really so much about the Unix in question, it's more about the cron daemon being used.

Comment: @JodieC Could you suggest a method that is portable?

Comment: @delh: In your example there's no need for a slash at all. Every minute: five asterisks. Every hour: an integer between 0 and 59 followed by four asterisks.

Comment: I realised that now. I was doing confusing stuff. I should sleep more I can't even count to five any more!